# selecting multiple max values from multiple ranges

Tags: r, function, max

I'm looking to find multiple max values using multiple ranges from a single table without using a loop.

It's difficult to explain, but here's an example:

```
list of value <- c(100, 110, 54, 64, 73, 23, 102)
beginning_of_max_range <- c(1, 2, 4)
end_of_max_range <- c(3, 5, 6)
```

### output

110, 110, 73

1. max(100, **110**, 54)
2. max(**110**, 54, 64)
3. max(64, **73**, 23)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do this with `mapply` -

```
list_of_value <- c(100, 110, 54, 64, 73, 23, 102)
beginning_of_max_range <- c(1, 2, 4)
end_of_max_range <- c(3, 5, 6)

mapply(function(x, y) max(list_of_value[x:y]), beginning_of_max_range, end_of_max_range)
#[1] 110 110  73
```

We create a sequence from `beginning_of_max_range` to `end_of_max_range`, subset it from `list_of_value` and get the `max` from each pair.